# RequestDispatcher Forward to already loaded JSP

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, servlets

I haven't worked in server side in a while and any help is really appreciated.

I am trying to create a small application that has an index.jsp page. The page has a button which when invoked calls a public SaaS API that does something in an external server with no changes to the view in the browser (still has index.jsp loaded).When the external job is done, my callback servlet is called by the service.

Now I need to update a component of the JSP when the callback servlet is called. So, I am doing a request.forward to the already loaded index.jsp with an attribute which when found in the JSP will invoke a javascript function.

The problem is I am unable to invoke the javascript function at all. I tried document.onload or window.load or document.ready etc. and none of these functions are getting called upon the request.forward to the index.jsp, since it is already loaded.

What is the best solution for this? Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: what is that you wish to do with that js function? show/hide things or something complex?

Comment: Nothing complex. Just want to invoke .focus on a list component, the list component chosen is based on the attribute.

Comment: Who invokes your callbackservlet? is it the extrenal saas api?

Comment: Yes. External SaaS API.

Comment: If thats the case, the response from the servlet is returned to the caller which in your case is the external api. The page that was loaded in your browser is a result of the request you had sent.

Answer (score 0):

You should model your interactions in such a way that on your button click, send the request to a servlet. From the servlet call the external saas api.
When it completes return the response to the servlet(assuming you want a blocking model). Put the data in the request and forward it to the jsp.

Comment: That is not possible in my case since I am using a telephony service and need to make my browser a client. Also on your previous point, I forward the request to index.jsp using request dispatcher from the callback servlet. So, it is not going back to the external api, I checked that. It is loading the jsp with the updated attributes. But I just can't invoke the JavaScript with the updated attributes.